# After Logging in How to change the sub components based on routing through nav links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Sorry if the title is not making much sense but my problem  is that I am redirecting from login page to main page and my Routes are like this

App.jsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/main/" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

now after getting redirected to the Main.jsx, I want to have a header and and side navbar always there but on selection of option from side navbar I want rest of my portion of the Main page to change components like (About, Contact ...)

I have tried to nest the routes (of which I have zero knowledge) but that surely didn't work out..

Main.jsx

```
<>
    <section className="main_container">
        <div style={menuStyles} className="nav">
            <Nav />
        </div>
        <div className="head">
            <button
                style={btnStyles}
                className="btn menu_btn"
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                {menuOpen ? 'close' : 'Menu'}
            </button>
            <div className="p_wrapper">
                <p>{email[0]?.toUpperCase()}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="body">
            {/* Something Like this */}
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/main/dash"
                    element={<DashBoard email={email} />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/main/about"
                    element={<About />}
                />
                <Route
                    path="/main/contact"
                    element={<Contact />}
                />
            </Routes>
        </div>
    </section>
</>;
```

Clearly this is not working,

and I am hoping someone can help me on how to do this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Main` component is rendering ***descendent*** routes then the parent route should append a `"*"` wildcard matcher to its path. In `react-router@6` all routes are *always* exactly matched, but the wildcard matcher allows descendent routes in more deeply nested children components to also be matched and rendered.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/main/*" element={<Main />} />
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Since it appears that this `Main` component is a bit of a layout component you could also convert it to a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) where it renders an `Outlet` component for ***nested*** routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

Main

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

...

<section className="main_container">
  <div style={menuStyles} className="nav">
    <Nav />
  </div>
  <div className="head">
    <button
      style={btnStyles}
      className="btn menu_btn"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      {menuOpen ? 'close' : 'Menu'}
    </button>
    <div className="p_wrapper">
      <p>{email[0]?.toUpperCase()}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="body">
    <Outlet /> // <-- Nested routes render content here
  </div>
</section>
```

App

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/main" element={<Main />}>
      <Route path="dash" element={<DashBoard email={email} />} />
      <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
      <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: hey man, both of your solutions are working fine! Big Big thanks for the help. Hope you have a Great day : )